# R Simmer Discrete-Event Simulation Dificulties

Tags: r

This is a Discrete-Event Simulation using R with the package Simmer.

I have a problem where my customers are leaving the queue if a call or a message is over 5 minutes.
My goal is to make the customers leave only if the call is over 5 minutes, and not if both of them are over 5 minutes.

```
library(simmer)
set.seed(2023)

Call_Or_Message <- function(x) rexp(1, 1/40)

Call <- function(x) runif(1) < 0.85
Message <- function(x) !Call(x)
Schedule_Appointment <- function(x) runif(1) < 0.30
Phone_Consultation <- function(x) runif(1) < 0.60
In_Person_Consultation <- function(x) runif(1) < 0.10

Screening_Questions <- function(x) rnorm(1, 4, 1)
Time_Decision_Consultation <- function(x) rnorm(1, 1, 0.25)
Time_Schedule_Appointment <- function(x) rnorm(1, 1, 0.25)

# Define the combined patient interaction trajectory
patient_interaction <- trajectory("patient") %>%
  log_(
    function() {
      if (Call()) {
        return("A call has come in")
      } else {
        return("A message has arrived")
      }
    }
  ) %>%
  renege_in(
    5,  
    out = trajectory() %>%
      log_("Patient abandoned the waiting line as the waiting time exceeded 5 minutes.")
  ) %>%
  seize("administrator", 1) %>%
  renege_abort() %>%
  timeout(Screening_Questions) %>%
  log_("Screening completed") %>%
  timeout(Time_Decision_Consultation) %>% 
  log_("Decision made") %>%
  branch(
    Schedule_Appointment, continue = FALSE,
    trajectory() %>%
      log_("Do not schedule an appointment") %>%
      release("administrator") %>%  
      log_("Process completed")
  ) %>%
  branch(
    Phone_Consultation, continue = FALSE,
    trajectory() %>%
      log_("Schedule a phone consultation") %>%
      timeout(Time_Schedule_Appointment) %>%
      log_("Appointment scheduled via phone") %>%
      release("administrator") %>% 
      log_("Process completed")
  ) %>%
  log_("Schedule an appointment in person") %>%
  timeout(Time_Schedule_Appointment) %>%
  log_("Appointment scheduled in person") %>%
  release("administrator") %>%  # Release the administrator
  log_("Process completed")

# Create the simulation environment
env <- simmer("Surgery Service Management")

# Add resources and generators
env %>%
  add_resource("administrator", 2) %>%
  add_generator("patient", patient_interaction, function() Call())

# Run the simulation
env %>% 
  run(150)
```

Sorry if i didnt explained myself well, but thank you in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.